# Do..While loop keeps repeating, Scanner issue

Tags: java, loops, do-while

```
do {   
    System.out.println("Set the A param: ");
    if(input.hasNextDouble() == true) {
        A = input.nextDouble();
        if(A == 0) {
            System.out.println("Param A cannot be a 0!");
        }
    } else if(input.hasNextDouble() == false) {
        System.out.println("Param A must be a number!");
    }
} while(A == 0 || input.hasNextDouble() == false);
```

Hello, I'm really new in Java and I found an obstacle I can't resolve by myself.

Everything is okay until I enter some letter instead of number, then this do..while loop keeps repeating itself.

After some search I suppose this might be a problem with a Scanner buffer becouse I should clear it before every loop with `input.nextLine()` but I don't really know where in code should I put it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: describe me , then i will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just want to get the value of A which should not be equal to 0 . Read comments

```
double A=0;
do {   
    System.out.println("Set the A param: ");
    if(input.hasNextDouble() == true) { //check for valid value 
        A = input.nextDouble();
        if(A == 0) {
            System.out.println("Param A cannot be a 0!");
        }
    } else{ // no valid value found , print msg and jump over the previous input
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Param A must be a number!");
    }
} while(A == 0); // just check , if the desired value is received 
                 // previously input.hasNextDouble() had no use cuz we already              
                 // checked no double value found so will be false, don't use it
```

Answer (score 1):

You only actually *consume* data from the scanner if `input.hasNextDouble()` is `true`.

Currently, if `A == 0` and there are non-numeric data in the buffer then you'll indeed loop indefinitely.

You need to consume data from the buffer on all control paths. In particular, if there is something non-numeric in the buffer, then you need to consume and immediately discard it: `input.next();` would be adequate.

Comment: Can't use `nextDouble()` to skip bad input when `hasNextDouble()` returns false. That would just throw an `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: hence my writing statement **like**. I've spelt it out carefully now.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not write the opposing check in an `else if`. Just use `else`. And you shouldn't check `== true`, since the value is already a boolean.

Now, for you infinite loop problem, when [`hasNextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--) is false, it means that the user entered something wrong (ignoring the potential end-of-stream issue). In that case you need to *discard* that bad input, which is best done by calling [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--).

Java naming convention states that variables should start with lowercase letter, so `A` should be `a`.

Your code then becomes:

```
double a = 0;
do {   
    System.out.println("Set the A param: ");
    if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        a = input.nextDouble();
        if (a == 0) {
            System.out.println("Param A cannot be a 0!");
        }
    } else {
        input.nextLine(); // discard bad input
        System.out.println("Param A must be a number!");
    }
} while (a == 0);
```

Comment: And this answer is quality too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for both answers, after first I wrote this:

```
        do
        {   

            System.out.println("Podaj wartość parametru A: ");

            if(input.hasNextDouble() == true)
            {
                A = input.nextDouble();
                if(A == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Parametr A nie może być zerem!");
                }
            }
            else if(input.hasNextDouble() == false)
            {
                System.out.println("Parametr A musi być liczbą!");
                input.nextLine();
                A = 0;
            }

        } while(A == 0);
```

And it worked but thanks to the second answer now I know how to do it better. :)
Thanks both of you once again.

Comment: dude you don't have to post your answer because it's already here so just accept the answer you like by clicking on the tick symbol against answer

Comment: Yeah but this is still an answer. And a good one. I upvoted it.